# Log error saying file encrypted but the file is not

Tags: umra

I am using UMRA by Tools4ever and getting this error.

> Error decrypting text. Cannot decompose encoded and encrypted input text.
>   Error '-1' while changing the password for the Google user '%username%' in the Google domain '%GoogleSessionId%'. Error decrypting Password.
>   Error in action 'Google User change password'. Script continues.

The file that this is pulling the username and password from is a file that I created by right clicking and selecting "new text file" and pasted the information in. I also attempted typing the same information into a new file to get past any possibility that something followed that shouldn't have.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific tool with vendor-provided technical support. Contact the vendor at http://www.tools4ever.com/services/supportservices/.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using an **Set Encrypted variable** action when setting the password for **Google Setup Connection** or the `reset password` action for Google. If you are still having problems, then please call our support hotline or chat at `Tools4ever.com`